# The result of the code is not displayed in the browser and there is no error in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

This is postController.php code:

```
public function index()
{


    $posts = post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();


    return view('posts.index', compact('posts'));

}
```

Also I make Route ( web.php ):

```
Route::resource('post','PostController');
```

This is view ( index.blade.php ) code:

```
@section('content')

    @foreach($posts as $post)

    <div class="panel">
       <div class="panel-heading">
           <h3>{{ $post -> title }}</h3>
       </div>

       <div class="panel-body">
              {{ $post -> body }}
       </div>
    </div>

    @endforeach

@endsection
```

After all of that I cannot find the error why my result doesn't display from data base

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhZ9a.png]

This tables should be displayed from database

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZaJ6.png]

When I try another way the result was displayed u can see that when I write at postController.php code:

```
public function index()
{

    $posts = post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get();

    return $posts;   

}
```

It showed from data base but there is also problem here ! Why the code is not displayed in a neat way in browser

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnUj0.png]

Comment: All relevant code needs to be posted here directly as text, and ideally as an [mcve].

Comment: lets see the post model

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

try print post variable on post.index.blade using 
`{{dd($posts)}}`. if your getting $posts variable on blade than everything fines.if not than `dd("some meassage")` into your index() to check if your index method actually get call.

if your index() method does not print `dd("some message")` than in terminal type `php artisan route:list` to check if your routes is prefix with something.

Comment: When I write php artisan route:list this is what I see

Comment: in your sample data i can see that object is inside of array. so try     `$posts = post::orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->get()->first();` or in blade do this `@foreach($posts[0] as $post)`.